# Eclipse with JAR - Classpath on OpenSuse 12.1

Tags: linux, java, mysql, eclipse, jar

howdy!

well i am brandnew to eclipse - i never ever used it so far!

i run a OpenSuse Linux Version 12.1 - and all works fine.

i am currently tryin to install the OSMGenerator - a tool that allows to put OpenStreetMap files
into MySQL-databases therefore i have to setup Eclipse.

Firstly i have to setup Eclipse
The OSMGenerator is set up as an Eclipse project, so i should be able to use it directly from within Eclipse (along with all the build&jar options).
One thing i will need, however, as a dependency on another project of the developer skyebook i have to grab this JAR - and add it to my classpath.

i need these JAR http://betaville.net/webstart/BetavilleApp.jar

Well one question - where is my classpath?
look forward to hear from you
greetings

The links again; https://github.com/skyebook/OSMGenerator
http://betaville.net/webstart/BetavilleApp.jar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to open the project properties (right click on project and then select "build path"->"configure build path" . Afterwards, you'll see a screen like this one:

[image]

Click on "Add JARs" on the right if you want to add a JAR that resides inside your project or alternativly click on "Add External JARs" if they're located just somewhere on your hard disk. The first option is preferable though.

Comment: hello dear Dariop - many thanks, Guess  that this image is one of the Eclipse - i am happy that you showed me  such good illstration. i do as you adviced - and come back  and report all my findings. greetings zero